# Generate App with multi language support with Tuist

Tags: xcode, tuist

my app, which i am setting up with [tuist](https://tuist.io/), is supposed to support localization.
how can I configure this in the tuist project?

Answer (score 0):

In your Resources folder for the target, you can create multiple folders with the locale name like this:

- `Resources/`

  - `Base.lproj/`

    - `Localizable.strings`
  - `da.lproj/`

    - `Localizable.strings`
  - `pl.lproj/`

    - `Localizable.strings`

When setting up your target in the `Project.swift` file in Tuist, you specify the resources path like `.., resources: "Resources/**"..`. Tuist will then make sure the Xcode project is generated with the proper languages set up.

Comment: not ".lrpoj", it should ".lproj"